# Using a function without callback C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to call a function which requires a callback:

```
cookie_monster->SetCookieWithOptionsAsync(
   ext_url, "dummy=value", options, &callback_function));
```

What do I do if I don't want to call any callback function?
Is there something like set `NULL`?

```
cookie_monster->SetCookieWithOptionsAsync(
   ext_url, "dummy=value", options, NULL);
```

Comment: If the function allows NULL or calls it without checking the pointer depends on the function - check the docs/try it out.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the function. If, in the body of the function, the code tests whether or not `callback_function` is `NULL` before calling it, you'll be OK. Otherwise, you'll have a segfault and your program will crash.

In that case, you'll need to pass in an empty/do-nothing callback to accomodate the API.

Comment: how do i add a function wich does nothing?

Comment: You need to create a callback that matches the description of `callback_function` which simply calls `return`.

Comment: void NullFunction(void) { return; }  how do i call that function?